# what is the property name for registering an user type in hibernate

Tags: hibernate, usertype, hibernate.cfg.xml

Accoriding to hibernate document: **section 6.5. Type registry**:
http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.6/reference/en-US/html/types.html

We can create a new user type and override existing hibernate's basic types. To use the new user type we need to register it using (see above link):

```
Configuration cfg = ...;
cfg.registerTypeOverride( new SuperDuperStringType() );
```

But never in document mentioned how we can register it in hibernate.cfg.xml? I can't believe they forgot to add this to hibernate.cfg.xml, Does anybody know about this?
Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look at that post: [Mapping A Custom Type In Hibernate](http://alenovarini.wikidot.com/mapping-a-custom-type-in-hibernate)

It worked for me with the following little modification:

the hibernate-mapping closing tag is wrongly formed, it misses the `/` (slash).

Appart from that, it explains everything.

Comment: I'm not sure how this got flagged as correct, the original question was how to override a basic type (i.e. String, Date, etc) in a generic form.  The link explains how to map a specific column to a different type.

Answer (score 4):

Sorry, for the omission.  The documentation describes both the registry and the keys, but to an extent expects users to be able to deduce that 1+1=2.  I'll make that more explicit.

http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.6/reference/en-US/html/types.html#types-value-basic Describes the built-in registration keys.

As you can see in that section, the default mapping in the registry for `java.lang.String` is to `org.hibernate.type.StringType`.  So when Hibernate sees an attribute whose java type is `java.lang.String` it looks into this registry using `java.lang.String` as the "registration key".  Again, this is all by default; you can still give explicit type information on each attribute if you wish.  That is described elsewhere in the documentation.  Basically you would use `@Type` or `<type/>`.

If you want Hibernate to use your `SuperDuperStringType` anytime there is no explicit type information supplied, you'd use "java.lang.String" as `SuperDuperStringType`'s `getRegistrationKeys()`:

```
public class SuperDuperStringType implements BasicType {
    ...

    @Override
    public String[] getRegistrationKeys() {
        // lets use delegation and register ourselves under all of StringType's keys
        return org.hibernate.type.StringType.INSTANCE.getRegistrationKeys();
    }
}
```

In that case nothing explicit is needed in the mappings.